# How do I remove values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the code I have written so far:

```
foreach ($link_body as $key => $unfinished_link)
{   
    #further Remove non ad links
    if (stristr($unfinished_link, "inactive" OR "nofollow") === TRUE)
    {   
        unset($link_body[$key]);
    }   

    echo "<font color='#FFFFFF' size='16'>$unfinished_link</font><br>";
}
```

I'm not getting any error messages but I keep getting results that look like this:

```
/cars/" />
/cars/">
/cars/" class="inactive">(not what I wanted)
/cars/" class="inactive">(not what I wanted)
/cars/" class="inactive">(not what I wanted)
/cars/" rel="nofollow">(not what I wanted)
/cars/?layout=gallery" rel="nofollow">(not what I wanted)
/cars/2001-ford-escort-great-condition/1235588">(IS what I wanted)
```

Where am I messing up here guys? Thx

Comment: `"inactive" OR "nofollow"` - this. You can't do this.

Comment: You need to do `if (stristr($unfinished_link, "inactive") || stristr($unfinished_link, "nofollow")) { ... }`

Comment: I have removed the OR and just left the "inactive"...still getting the same result

Comment: stristr does not return TRUE, the condition should be !== FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find a string inside that, maybe you indend to use `stripos` instead:

```
foreach ($link_body as $key => $unfinished_link) {
    // further Remove non ad links
    if(
        stripos($unfinished_link, 'inactive') !== false ||
        stripos($unfinished_link, 'nofollow') !== false
    ) {  
        unset($link_body[$key]);

    } else {
        echo "<font color='#FFFFFF' size='16'>$unfinished_link</font><br>";
        // make sure your background is not white, or else your text will not be seen, at least on the white screen
    }
}
```

If this is an HTML markup, consider using an HTML parser instead, `DOMDocument` in particular, and search for that attributes:

```
$rel = $node->getAttribute('rel'); // or
$class = $node->getAttribute('class');
```

Answer (score 1):

You echo the variable $unfinished_link that it's different that $link_body[$key]. OK, the values are the same before you unset $link_body[$key] but it's like you are doing:

```
$a=1;
$b=1;
unset($a);
echo $b;
```

Of course, this code will echo the number one because I have unset a variable and echo other one. Also the condition of the If is incorrect.

Comment: ok @Serpes I have echoed the $link_body[$key] but now Im getting an undefined offset error.

Comment: Obviusly. If you unset it you can't echo it. Or you echo it in an else statement or you use another if statement like: if(isset($link_body[$key]))

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove array's element *inside* foreach statement
Remember elements to delete in foreach, delete them after foreach:

```
$elements_to_delete = {};
foreach ($link_body as $key => $unfinished_link)
{

    if(stristr($unfinished_link, "inactive" OR "nofollow") === TRUE) {   

        $elements_to_delete.push($key);
    }
}

// removing elements after foreach complete
foreach($key in $elements_to_delete){
    $link_body[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) :

```
function filterLink($link) {
 return  stripos($unfinished_link, 'inactive') === false &&
         stripos($unfinished_link, 'nofollow') === false
}

$unfinished_link = array_filter($unfinished_link, "filterLInk")
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot combine parameters in the way you try here :

```
if(stristr($unfinished_link, "inactive" OR "nofollow") === TRUE)
```

Instead, you can replace with

```
if(stristr($unfinished_link, "nofollow") === TRUE) || stristr($unfinished_link, "inactive") === TRUE)
```